# Read and analyse output data line by line

Tags: python-3.x

I have a program that reads specific lines of a file like so

```
with open("FastQ_Test.txt", "r") as infile:
c = 1
for line in infile:
    if c == 4:
       print(line)

        c = 1
    else:
        c += 1
```

And then create a dictionary from the results like this, that outputs ASCII values less than a said number and its index

```
for text in line:
    char = ord(text)
    print(char, end = " ")
    num += 1
    result[char] = set()
    result[char].add(num)

    row = list(result.keys())

    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[i] < 80:
           print('[', row[i], ':', result[row[i]], ']', end=" ")
```

Don't mind the indenting and all. 
What my problem is, is I would like to analyse the lines read from the first piece of code. line by line. What it does is, it analyses the first line perfectly but when it comes to the other lines, it reads from where the first line ends.

E.g. File

```
    WDDDDFRWWW
    +
    RFFWEGDDEE
    +
    TTTDDDEEWW
```

Desired output, after reading lines 1, 3 and 5

```
    line 1 -> [87: {1, 8, 9, 10}, 68: {2, 3, 4, 5}, 70: {6}, 82: {7}]
    line 2 -> [82: {1}, 70: {2, 3}, 87: {4}, 69: {5, 9, 10}, 71: {6}, 68: {7, 8}]
```

and so forth.

Comment: the question is not clear please elaborate and provide an example input and desired output

Comment: There is no input by a user. It is supposed to read a line from a file and output  eg [64: {1, 2, 3}, 71: {4, 5, 7}, 73: {6, 8}] which will be from the first line. And then do the same for the next line but what it does is [64: { 9, 11, 12}, 71: {10, 13, 15}] instead of having a separate index for line 2, also starting at 1. So it counts the lines per character and not per line

Comment: edit your question and add a file with couple of lines and the desired output from the script when processing this file

Comment: I have done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a clue of what is your goal here but below is a simple script that should give you the desired output

I tried to change as little as possible but to introduce new ideas and technics as much as possible, hope this will help

```
with open("FastQ_Test.txt", "r") as infile, open("output.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == '+':
            continue

        result = {}
        for i, text in enumerate(line.strip()):
            char = ord(text)
            if char not in result.keys():
                result[char] = set()
            result[char].add(i + 1)

        row = list(result.keys())

        print_list = []
        for i in result.keys():
            print_list.append("{}: {}".format(i, result[i]))
        # print("[{}]".format(", ".join(print_list)))
        outfile.write("[{}]\n".format(", ".join(print_list)))
```

output

```
[87: {8, 1, 10, 9}, 68: {2, 3, 4, 5}, 70: {6}, 82: {7}, 10: {11}]
[82: {1}, 70: {2, 3}, 87: {4}, 69: {9, 10, 5}, 71: {6}, 68: {8, 7}, 10: {11}]
[84: {1, 2, 3}, 68: {4, 5, 6}, 69: {8, 7}, 87: {9, 10}]
```

Comment: This actually helps a lot. Thank you so much

Comment: Is there a way that I can write this result onto a different file? It constantly gives me the last line, when I try and not the entire list.

Comment: @Thatile, refactor the code to write output to file, hope this answer your question

Comment: I understand what you mean. I am just not sure how to do it. My output doesn't look the way I want it to

Comment: @Thatile I'm afraid I don't understand the issue, can you provide the output and the desired one, also the code